# Python: How to match the first matching pattern

Tags: python-2.7

Python progamming. 
Python 2.4.3

I have a string:

```
x = "set_ccci_path 2 -setup -from [get_clocks abc_clk] -to [all_registers -clock xyz_clk -data_pins] -start"
```

When I use

```
y = re.match(r'(.*)(get_clocks)\s+(.*)(\])(.*)$', x, re.M|re.I)
```

I got `y.group(3)` as:

```
abc_clk] -to [all_registers -clock xyz_clk -data_pins
```

What I want is `abc_clk`. How do I do this?

Comment: y = re.match(r'(.*)(get_clocks)\s+(.*)(\])(.*)$', x, re.M|re.I)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
y = re.match(r'(.*)\[((get_clocks)(\s+)(?P<c>\w+))\](.*)$', x, re.M|re.I) 
y.group('c')
```

Comment: thanks ! It works for this case..  I think following one is better since \w+ may not work for any strings (includes the multiple strings with space. .

Answer (score 0):

Change the third group to exclude closing braces, and you'll get the result you want.

```
import re
x = "set_ccci_path 2 -setup -from [get_clocks abc_clk] -to [all_registers -clock xyz_clk -data_pins] -start"
y = re.match(r'(.*)(get_clocks)\s+([^\]]*)(])(.*)$', x, re.M|re.I)
print y.group(3)
```

Comment: `[^\]]*` It means match anything thats not an ending square brace.